# I guess *go over* and *work* are interchangeable here, is my understanding right?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU?t=324) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)  (sentence_1)

> Despite the country's love for Grylls, however, the Chinese version didn't *go over* well.

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-over) dictionary gives this explanation about "go over"

> to be received in a particular way

and this example (sentence_2)

> Do you think my speech went over OK

from which, I cannot get a clear point.

I guess *go over* and *work* are interchangeable here, is my understanding right?

Comment: Kind of, because "work" in this context means to be received in a kindly manner, as in the expression, "That works for me." Grylls is a person who's video presentations are generally well received, but not his Chinese episode. If this were about barbecue grills made in China, they might be ill received because they didn't work (i.e., operate properly) or because they were the wrong color. We can't tell from the statement.

Comment: @user105719 Thanks for your comments, consider sentence_2, does "to be received" mean "my speech would be received something"?

Comment: It means how the audience received it and responded to it. If they applauded, your speech was well received or it went over OK. If they rioted, not so much.

Comment: @user105719 Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: You're welcome, and you're kind to offer to accept an equivalent answer should I write one. Thank you in return. I'm confident that I'm correct, but I'm just not up to the effort it would take to document the answer properly.  I know that makes me a bad cyber-citizen here, but it's either that or not providing something useful at all.